# Vim: Netrw used to equate "%" to the folder being examined

Tags: netrw

When I used previous versions of Netrw, I could issue Bash commands like `:!mkdir %/NewSubFolder`.  The `%` would translate into the folder being examined by Netrw, which isn't necessarily the same as the "present working directory" returned by `:pwd`.

If I try `:!mkdir %/NewSubFolder` in Netrw v168, I get:

```
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"
```

Is there a simple way to get the old behaviour of `%` back?  I found it to be very useful.

Comment: I'm using v171 and I have the desired behavior. FWIW, you can use Netrw's `d` to create a subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks, that does help.  However, I'd like to be able to access the text for `%` because in the past, some of the `Netrw` functions just didn't work.  Also, I have far more flexibility with the text of `%`, e.g., `:!mkdir -p %/A/deeply/nested/folder` or `:!ls % >| %/Listing.txt` or `:!echo %/DesiredFileName | putclip`, where `putclip` is any system command to put the contents of the input (`stdin`) into the system clipboard.

Comment: I am using latest version of netrw as of this writing (v171 in vim 9.0) and `:!echo %` has the desired behavior.

Comment: OK, that's good to know.  The limitation that I'm experiencing will disappear when v171 gets to the Cygwin repository.  Thanks.